# Apple Script execute Unix executable

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, applescript

I'm currently pulling my hair out trying to make an apple script execute a shell script / Unix executable, so that I can drag it into the dock. I don't have much experience with AS, so this is propably an easy fix for many of you guys.

Here's the whole script:

```
to run
    do shell script "/Users/MyUserName/Documents/cmus/2.7.1_1/bin/cmus"
end run
```

Cmus is a terminal music program that is a Unix executable.

When I try to run it, I get this error message:

```
error "Error opening terminal: unknown." number 1
```

What is the problem? Pls help...

Comment: What is the output of the command: `echo $TERM`?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.. How do I check this?

Comment: Open Terminal.app and paste that command... it should output something.

Comment: `xterm-256color`  <--- this is the output

Comment: Post more of your script... surely that's not all of it.

Comment: Well the first code segment I posted is everything I have in the editor. I didn't know I needed to include extra things... What do I need to preface the code with?

Comment: If you explained a bit more about what you're expecting your script to do then posting the rest wouldn't be necessary; the more background about your code the better usually. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing your program is `curses` based and needs a Terminal window, so try this:

```
to run
   tell application "Terminal"
      do script "/Users/MyUserName/Documents/cmus/2.7.1_1/bin/cmus"
   end tell
end run
```

Comment: That's a first! A down vote before I have even finished typing/checking my answer! And without any explanation - how very polite! NOT!

Comment: That's a fine attitude when I am trying to help someone. A simple, polite comment would have sufficed, and helped more.

Comment: I feel your pain, and completely agree... +1

Comment: @djbazziewazzie I agree that truly awful, grossly incorrect answers may be downvoted, but I disagree with gratuitously downvoting constructive answers that are not quite perfect but are still in the right direction and help to actually get close to solving the problem - and maybe spur others on to get the exact answer. They will naturally fall lower down the page of their own accord as a result of other, better answers floating to the top.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quic reply. Yes I want to open a terminal window to execute the file, but when using your code I get this error:

Comment: `error "„Terminal“ recieved an error: Error opening terminal: unknown." number 1`

Comment: `to run
 tell application "Terminal"
  do shell script "export TERM=xterm"
  do shell script "/Users/LucaHoelzel/Documents/cmus/2.7.1_1/bin/cmus"
 end tell
end run`

Comment: Like this? Above the other do shell line? Nope, same error :(

Comment: @TheUnderBrony don't use `do shell script` but use `do script`. `do shell script` is part of the standard addition.osax which open an shell in the background `do script` is part of the terminal which will execute the string in a terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

> @TheUnderBrony don't use do shell script but use do script. do shell script is part of the standard addition.osax which open an shell in the background do script is part of the terminal which will execute the string in a terminal window.-  dj bazzie wazzie

This solved my problem, thank you! But Only one slight problem is left: The terminal starts and opens the program, but it opens it in the background, aka, I need to click on the terminal icon to show the window. Do I need to activate the window? If so, how? But already thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Yes, inside the `tell application "Terminal"` block you can add the line `activate` and terminal will become the frontmost application.